# On Ubuntu 22,04: Upgraded OpenSSL from 3.0.2 to 3.0.7; `openssl version` command still shows 3.0.2 for library

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, version

I have just manually upgraded OpenSSL from 3.0.2 to 3.0.7.  I know a patch was available for 3.0.2, but, easier to answer to management this way vs. having to explain over and over again why the version still shows 3.0.2.  So no need to comment on that.

I ran into the 'unable to lookup symbol BIO_f_zlib' error initially
after the install when using:

```
config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl share zlib
```

Changed the config to:

```
config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl no-comp
```

and this was successful.

Now that my install is complete, I am seeing that the `openssl version` command is showing:

```
OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
```

How do I correct my installation so that the Library version matches the Binary version?
NOTE:

- I updated `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with a file named `openssl-3.0.7.conf`
  with `/usr/local/ssl/lib` for contents.
- I have also changed the system environment PATH var to include `/usr/local/ssl/bin`.
- I executed `ldconfig -v` and `source /etc/environment` after the updates
  (no joy) and finally rebooted (still no joy).

Still seeing the mismatch in the `openssl version` output.

I tried the suggestion to re-link `libssl.so.3`, with no success. 
See below environmental info and trailing `openssl version` output. 
New OpenSSL (3.0.7) was installed to `/usr/local/ssl`
per the config option on the build.

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

# find /usr/local -name 'libssl.so*'
/usr/local/qualys/cloud-agent/lib/libssl.so.1.1
/usr/local/qualys/cloud-agent/lib/libssl.so
/usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so.3
/usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so
/usr/local/lib64/libssl.so
/usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.3_3.0.2 <== renamed from libssl.so.3
/usr/local/src/openssl-3.0.7/libssl.so.3
/usr/local/src/openssl-3.0.7/libssl.so

# ls -l /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32 Nov  2 17:07 /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so -> /usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 809464 Nov  1 15:55 /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.3_3.0.2

# ls -l /usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 Nov  1 21:23 /usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so -> libssl.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 808704 Nov  1 21:23 /usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so.3

# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

built on: Thu Oct 27 17:06:56 2022 UTC

platform: debian-amd64

options:  bn(64,64)

compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/openssl-WsPfAX/openssl-3.0.2=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2

OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"

ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3"

MODULESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ossl-modules"

Seeding source: os-specific

CPUINFO: OPENSSL_ia32cap=0xfefa32035f8bffff:0x1c2ffb
```

What have I missed
and how can I make sure processes using the library
are using the correct version library?

Comment: Ubuntu has backported the changes to openssl 3.0.2 however it still suck that openssl 3 is not up to date

Comment: For context, as it wasn't directly referenced, though could be considered seriously by anyone looking for a genuinely secure against CVE(s) Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/1438590/355456

Comment: *easier to answer to management this way vs. having to explain over and over again why the version still shows 3.0.2*  **No, it's not**.  What happens for the *next* vulnerability?  Distros like Ubuntu patch vulnerabilities in components like OpenSSL - that's why you run `apt upgrade`.  Manually updating components yourself results in **you** becoming a Linux distro builder and maintainer. You're not qualified, are you? Did you test **everything** that depends on OpenSSL to make sure your manual update didn't break anything?  Are you going to spend the time watching CVEs for the next time?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your libraries are not updated. Beside updating OpenSSL you also would need to update corresponding libraries (libssl in this case). Best would be to:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

And manually updating OpenSSL may corrupt some of its usage - libraries will not fit to other on the system, so the best way to do that is by the two above commands. Your system may not be ready to support newer version of OpenSSL than in the repo.

The other way around is to manually update all libraries along. So if you first update OpenSSL manually, then update libssl manually and going further into other libraries - manually too. However you may end up with need to upgrade the whole system to newer edition what is obviously not advised.

Comment: Look at the list of installed files: the updated library was installed, the problem is that it’s not found at runtime.

Comment: @StephenKitt and that's the reason manual installation does not work. If you go with these two commands it should install most recent version that this OS accepts.

Comment: Of course, but the OP explicitly doesn’t want that: “I know a patch was available for 3.0.2, but, easier to answer to management this way vs. having to explain over and over again why the version still shows 3.0.2. So no need to comment on that.”

Comment: @StephenKitt I've given best resolution in that particular case. If you know better answer please feel free to share it.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  The apt update/upgrade was done first and, unfortunately, management did not like the result.  @StephenKitt was correct.  I find it hard to believe that there is no way to fix this.  I provided all the displays above to show the resultant environment and hopefully shortcut this for anyone able to help with this.  What library is missing or not updated causing the discrepancy in the version display?  This is purely to resolve a hot and recently published vulnerability.

Comment: @SeekingGuidance that means your management expects from you to do impossible. You can't update one program, without updating libraries, and later next libraries. For now the solution is to upgrade whole system to next edition - that's the only way to upgrade program and libs to a specific version.

Comment: @SeekingGuidance your problem is fixable, I just haven’t had time to write it up.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your OpenSSL binary was correctly upgraded to version 3.0.7, but the library is still pointing to the old version 3.0.2. To fix this, you need to update the library path to point to the new version.

First, check where your OpenSSL library is located. Based on your find command output, it seems to be in **/usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so.3**.

Next, you need to update the library path for the system to look for the new version. You have already added **/usr/local/ssl/lib** to **/etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl-3.0.7.conf**, but you need to also run the **ldconfig** command to update the library cache with the new path:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

This should update the library cache to include the new OpenSSL library path.

Finally, check if the library version has been updated by running:

```
ldd $(which openssl)
```

This should show the library path used by openssl. If it still shows the old version, try running ldd with the path to the openssl binary in /usr/local/ssl/bin.

If the library path has been updated, running openssl version should now show the correct version for both the binary and the library.

```
openssl version -a
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The question says they've already done this

Comment: This risks breaking anything in the OS that relies on OpenSSL.  You're not a Linux distro builder nor maintainer, you're not testing any of the components of the OS that rely on OpenSSL when you do this.  And you're not prepared to spend the time and effort to keep your now-custom Linux install up-to-date for the **next** CVE that comes out.

Answer (score 0):

The `prefix=/usr/local/ssl` is not the default OpenSSL isstalaltion prefix on Ubuntu 22. You now have a new version on `/usr/local/ssl` and a default one. You may try to build with the following options

```
export CONFARGS  = --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl --libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5 no-zlib no-ssl3 enable-unit-test no-ssl3-method enable-rfc3779 enable-cms no-capieng
    
./Configure shared $(CONFARGS)  linux-x86_64  && perl configdata.pm -d
make -j4 
make install
```

Maybe create a `.deb` package and test it before installing.

Comment: In what environment can you say `export` with whitespace before and after the `=`,  and assign a multi-word string to a variable without quotes?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' looks like a line from the Makefile